# Can we create instance objects using javassist without using reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, javassist

How can I create instance objects using javassist without using reflection API?

```
Class cls = Class.forName("className");
Object obj = cls.getConstructor().newInstance();

CtClass ctClass = cp.get("className");
```

How can I get the instance of ctClass without using reflection API.

Comment: Why do you need to instantiate the CtClass. CtClass from javassist library stores the bytecode of any class loaded in JVM and provided methods get the details of class attributes, methods, constructors etc and modify the classes at the Bytecode level. As far as I know, If you need to re-instantiate the modified classes you should use Class.forName.

Comment: What’s wrong with using the Reflection API for something that is a Reflection operation?

Comment: yesterday you asked different question about comparing reflections api to javassist and few other things. But this is comparing apples to oranges. Javassist is for editing bytecode of classes, not for reflection and dynamic calls. Tho... if you insist I can still show you how to create something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Libraries like javassist are not for reflection but for generation/modification of code in runtime (instrumentation is required for modification of already loaded classes) or before class load, but... you can still use libraries like that to generate code that will call some method, so at the end you will do similar thing to reflections and dynamically call some method, but you are limited to methods that are accessible to you, so mostly only public ones. (there are ticks to call package protected ones, by defining class in same package + module if java 9 is used, but I will skip this here) Also at the end you will need to use reflections anyways - to create new instance of generated class that will create instance of other class without reflections.

Doing something like that is in many cases just pointless (tho avoiding reflections might save you some execution time, but in most cases it's not worth it, and first call will be extra slow). But if you insist then here you go:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Supplier<Test> testSupplier = creatorFor(Test.class);
        // this is reflection free now:
        System.out.println(testSupplier.get());
        System.out.println(testSupplier.get());
    }

    private static <T> Supplier<T> creatorFor(Class<T> type) throws Exception {
        String toCreate = type.getName();
        ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
        // create new class with some unique name
        CtClass generatorClass = pool.makeClass("generated." + toCreate + "Creator");
        // lets implement some common interface for easier usage
        generatorClass.addInterface(pool.getCtClass(Supplier.class.getName()));
        // and implement it method that will create new instance of our object
        CtMethod generatorMethod = CtNewMethod.make(
                "public Object get() { return new " + toCreate + "(); }",
                generatorClass);
        generatorClass.addMethod(generatorMethod);
        // the only reflective part we need:
        return (Supplier<T>) generatorClass.toClass().newInstance();
    }
}
```